# Setting per request Time.zone based on a model instance and keeping DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I have the following code:

```
around_filter :event_time_zone

def event_time_zone(&block)
  @event.present? ? Time.use_zone(@event.venue.time_zone_name, &block) : yield
end
```

I placed it in my ApplicationController.

The problem is that the instance variable @event is never set when this around_filter is called. It is however available before the action in every resource controller ( by use of CanCan), however I do not want to sprinkle a bunch of around_filter calls in all those controllers.

Is there a simple way that I can use this above code but not repeat myself everywhere?

I could do a user based time_zone, but what if a user is managing events in different time zones? The only relevant date to display would only ever be in the events time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue has to do with the ordering that the filters are firing, i.e. the around_filter is running before your filter that sets the `@event` variable

I personally would do this per controller as needed, your application will eventually have many controller/actions that have nothing to do with events.

- Setup user based timezone setting/handling which is handled in the application controller
- Set the timezone based on `@event` as needed to override user setting

You may be interested in this blog post I did on rails timezones (see also the example code on github) - http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: You're right about the firing order. Thanks for that blog post, I think this is all the information I need to figure this out. I've got everything working properly already, just sick of all the in_time_zone's sprinkled everywhere. With a couple of your convenience methods for the model and controller level, I can get rid of most of my TZ code. Thanks!